# Approach for doing Entity Relationships

Tags: 7

I'm looking for the best way to approach creating relationships using Drupal 7.  I am looking for advice on creating the following:

1) A "letter" content type (as in an old fashioned letter)
  a) From Person (i.e. "John Doe")
  b) Associated From address ("12348 Street")
  c) To Person
  d) Associated To address
  e) Postage Date
  f) File attachment of scanned letter

2) A person can have one or more addresses (I am recording some family history of letters sent and people have changed addresses over time)

3) Ability to select the Person/Address in the Letter content type for the From / To Person.

I've been reading the documentation, but I'm just unclear on the best approach.  Would appreciate suggestions. For example, I started out creating a field for From Name and To Name and From Address and To Address, but realized I'd be creating a lot of redundant data and that it would be better to create relationships, but am not sure how to accomplish that.  Should I create a Person Content type?  If not explicit instructions, would appreciate a general point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would create a *Person* content type in addition to the *Letter* content type.

You may also consider creating a *Place* (address) content type.  It depends on how many letters you have and how complex the requirements are for filtering the data later.

Depending on your situation, you could make some assumptions (such as if people are only going to live at one address at a time, if you track the time that they lived at such an address, then you just need to know the time the letter was sent, and then you can generate the address, etc.)

I would do something like this:

Content type *Letter*

- Field: Sender ([Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference), takes a *Person* content type)
- Field: Sender Address ([Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) that takes a *Place* content type)
- Field: Recipient ([Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference), takes a *Person* content type)
- Field: Recipient Address ([Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) that takes a *Place* content type)
- Field: Postage date ([Date](https://drupal.org/project/date))
- Field: Scanned letter (File field, built-in to core)

Content type *Person*

- Field: Name (Text, built-in to core)

Content type *Place*

- Field: Address ([Addressfield](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield))

With this approach, although it is a little complex to build, you can use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to build screens that show, say, all of the people who lived at an address, or all of the addresses at which a person has received letters.

Comment: I've implemented these suggestions, thanks.  Follow-up questions: 1) It occurred to me that I wanted to capture the maiden names and also reflect other name changes (i.e. my Danish relatives changed their names from Neilsen to Nelson to better fit in).  I was thinking I could allow for the Name field to allow for multiple entries, or could enter them as a new Name.  Since one letter might be from my grandmother using a name prior to her marriage and another using her married name later on, how best to reflect that?

Comment: Follow-up question 2) - I was also thinking of trying to create relationships of the people (spouse, child, etc.).  Thinking out loud - The person type would need to reference another person.  The more I think about it I think that you would need a Field for Spouse which takes a person type and then a Field for Child which takes a person type.  From there it seems like all of the other relationships could be caclulated ... does that sound like the right track?

Comment: For the names, I would either allow multiple values in the name field or have two name fields, one listing the name you want to use as an identifier (single value) and the other listing all alternate names (multiple values).

Comment: For creating relationships between people, you could create new Entity Reference fields as you suggested (one for spouse, one for children).  It will be a little complex to show the relationships, but that is the most logical way to set it up I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just general ideas, not a solution...

I would check out the entity reference module (https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) as a starting point, to get an idea of how it works, so you can plan your project with this in mind. Entity reference makes it easy to link one entity to another, then build views to generate lists of related items. Entity views attachment (EVA, https://drupal.org/project/eva) can help you attach views of related items to entities. (i.e. you could display a list of letters as a view attached to a person)

You may also want to check out the addressfield module (https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) especially if you have international addresses to work with. It's a little tweaky, since it handles the entire address as a single field, but it saves you the trouble of implementing several fields to catpture each address.

From your description, it seems like you would want at least these content types: letter, person, address (or place). But it's hard to say for sure without knowing your complete vision.